# PDF bigger than one

Tags: probability

I am calculating the probability density function of a system with a value of mean and variance of  2.12e-04 and 2.596e-08, respectively. The studied values where a vector between [0 1e-3].

The results that I have got with Matlab:

[0   705.7362   258.2455    139.5762     89.1093    62.4785    46.5355    36.1603   28.9943    23.8189 19.9486]

I studied that a PDF is lower than 1. Are those values wrong?

Comment: If your system only takes on a single value, then your PDF will be the Dirac delta distribution, which is infinitely tall (and infinitesimally thin).

Answer (score 2):

$1$ is not an upper bound for a pdf.

For example, uniform distribution over $[0,\frac12]$ attains value $2$.

$1$ is an upper bound for a probability which is obtained upon integrating the $pdf$, your domain is very small, hence we should expect them to have value beyond $1$.